# Tikz library: what prevents this code from working? Unable to call the sin() function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've tried to call a mathematical function in the x-coordinate part of an (x,y) coordinate, to no avail. Strangely it works for the y-coordinate. Something must be wrong with the syntax but I can't figure it out.

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] (.5,{cos(60)}); % WORKS
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] ({.5},{cos(60)}); % WORKS
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] ({sin(30)},.5); % ATTEMPT 1: DOES NOT WORK
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] (sin(30),.5); % ATTEMPT 2: DOES NOT WORK
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] ({sin(30)},{.5}); % ATTEMPT 3: DOES NOT WORK
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] ({sin(30),.5}); % ATTEMPT 4: DOES NOT WORK
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] {(sin(30),.5)}; % ATTEMPT 5: DOES NOT WORK
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] ({{sin(30)},.5}); % ATTEMPT 6: DOES NOT WORK
\draw (0,0) to [out=30,in=-120] {({sin(30)},.5)}; % ATTEMPT 7: DOES NOT WORK
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Best regards,

Comment: This reminds me of an old bug that I thought was fixed years ago. It has nothing to do with `sin`. The same thing will happen if you put `cos` or `tan` or `ln` or any function requiring parentheses in the first coordinate. An extra set of braces will fix this: `({{sin(30)}},.5)` but I'm not clear why Ti*k*Z removes the first set of braces from the first coordinate.

Comment: This especially happens with `to`. If you try `\draw (0,0) -- ({sin(30)},.5);` no error comes up.

Comment: the problem is that with implicit coordinates tikz has to decide if you have a name  (a) or a mathematical expression (1+2) or a dimension and such parsing can easily take the wrong way. `(xyz cs:x={sin(30)},y=.5);` would work, as does `(+{sin(30)},.5);` (but not `0+{sin(30)`).  But generally I would either calculate the result outside the coordinate first or use the fp-modul from LaTeX: `(\fpeval{sin(30)},0.5);`

Comment: Hi! You can use `calc` library and `($({sin(30)},.5)$)` in *attempt 1*.